# Can I freeze quince fruits before making jelly?

Tags: freezing, fruit, jelly

I have recently unexpectedly acquired a decent harvest of quinces.  I would like to make these into [jelly](https://www.thespruceeats.com/quince-jelly-recipe-1327853), but don't have time right now.

Can I freeze the quinces for a few months and then use them to make the jelly later?

If so, should I freeze them whole or prepared in some way?

Or is there a better way I can store them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ripen in an open container around room temperature. Peel optionally then slice and core. Sprinkle like 1/4 cup sugar and 1/2 teaspoon ascorbic acid (1500 mg) per few pounds of fruit; Let sit for ten minutes until a syrup forms and sugar is dissolved then gently mix to coat everything--add more sugar if you don't have such a syrup form. Then freeze in proper, moisture-resistant containers or freezer bags--leave head space. Alternatively you can ripen and extract the juice according to the recipe then simply freeze it. There's a chance freezing may break some of the fruit's pectin, so have some additional on hand and maybe test the thickness before sealing the cans. You can get a deeper red if you simmer the sweetened juice for a few hours, although *added* acidity may destroy your pectin if you go this long.

Comment: That looks like doing significant parts of the recipe for quince jelly. If OP doesn't have the  time to do jelly now I doubt they would have the time for that.

Comment: @quarague The difficulty is that the main reason for the existence of jelly is because other methods of keeping fruit either don't keep for that long or have difficult requirements (lots of fridge or cellar space).

Answer (score 8):

Quinces have similar storage properties as apples. This means storing them in the fridge at temperatures slightly above freezing and with high humidity will easily allow you to keep them for several weeks. If you have too many to put them in the fridge, keeping them in a cool, unheated basement or cellar will also work for multiple weeks. In both cases, sort out fruit that already have bad spots or other signs of decay and store the rest whole without any cutting or other preparation.